# Why would we want to combine the usage of classes and interfaces this way?

Tags: typescript, oop, types

In TypeScript's [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html), we see the following usage of classes and interfaces:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
 
class UserAccount {
  name: string;
  id: number;
 
  constructor(name: string, id: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
  }
}
 
const user: User = new UserAccount("Murphy", 1);
```

The class `UserAccount` is already type-checked. This means that when we instantiate the class and want to explicitly give it a data type, we would be able to do so by declaring `const user: UserAccount`. Or, if we want to keep the declaration as `const user: User`, we simply need to change the name of the class from `UserAccount` to `User`. In either case we do not need the interface. So, what is the point of having the interface in the application above?

Comment: I think the point of that example is just to show that you *can* do that, not that you necessarily *should* or would want to. That section is **very** terse, I wouldn't read much into it. (I think they missed an opportunity to point out that it doesn't matter whether you do `const user: User =` or `const user: UserAccount =` or just `const user =`, it would all come to the same thing, because `User` and `UserAccount` are interchangeable from a type perspective, since TypeScript's type system is *structural* [based on the shapes of things] not *nominal* [based on their names/identities], and...

Comment: ...the *types* `User` and `UserAccount` define the same thing. [The `class UserAccount` structure also defines a constructor function, but the *type* aspect is the same.])

Comment: I'm not sure how someone could answer this question authoritatively, as though there were a single correct answer to "why would someone write code like this?".  If the question were "why did the handbook authors put this code in there" then I suspect the above comments would be the right answer, although again, for a SO question it would be hard to answer this authoritatively without, say, grepping through edit history of that section and seeing if there were any comments that answer this.  So this whole thing feels very much like it's inviting opinions, one way or the other.

Comment: Why would you remove [the link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) to the documentation you're referring to?